# How can I mass-update my data in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

For a while I was using the deprecated .removeOnDisconnect() function to manage client presence, so some documents now permanently show that there are multiple viewers even if there is only one looking at their document. To fix this, I want to delete all children of "clients" for each scratchpad. I read through the docs, but couldn't find a good way to do this. Any suggestions?

My data tree looks like this:

`scratchpad.firebaseio.com/:scratchpad_id/clients/:client_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase doesn't have an operation like you describe (yet).

I'd recommend attaching a "child_added" callback at the root of your Firebase, and then for each child, deleting the "clients" location. This would require you to sync the entire Firebase, but for a server running Node.js that may not be a big deal.